# Select subset of one column, then compare to another

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file in pyspark with a great number of sales information - units, store id, total sales, customer loyalty, product number, etc.

I need to compare the sales numbers of customers who are in the loyalty plan against the sales numbers of customers who are not in the loyalty plan. All customers in the loyalty plan are represented in the "collector_key" field with a positive integer and those who are not are represented with a negative integer, like so:

```
>>> df.head(10)
  collector_key  sales
0             -1  42.72
1             -1  27.57
2   139517343969  62.44
3             -1   0.00
4             -1   0.00
5             -1   7.32
6             -1  64.51
7             -1   0.00
8   134466064080  20.72
9             -1   0.00
```

At first I thought that maybe I could use an if/else statement to shuffle the users into loyalty and non-loyalty lists. But then I thought that maybe it would be more efficient to just filter loyalty customers into their own dataframe and do the same with non-loyalty customers and then just subtract the two results. I thought maybe I could do a regex on the "collector_key" column:

```
non_loy_cust = test_1.filter(regex='^(-?\d+)\s+')
```

But then I'm not sure how to retain the "sales" column, since "regex" and "items" are mutually exclusive.

On top of that, I will need to sum up the sales columns so that I have a single number for loyalty and non-loyalty customers, but I think (once I overcome the previous hurdle) can do it with something like:

```
loy_sales = df.groupby('sales').max()
non_loy_sales = df2.groupby('sales').max()
```

Or there's maybe even an easier third option that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `.transform()`

```
# set group first
df['collector_key'] = df['collector_key'].map(lambda x: 0 if x == -1 else 1)


#loyalty (1) vs non-loyalty sales(0)
df.groupby('collector_key')['sales'].sum() 

   collector_key
0    142.12
1     83.16

# adding max sales column
df['max_sales'] = df.groupby('collector_key')['sales'].transform('max')

    collector_key   sales   max_sales
0        -1         42.72   64.51
1        -1         27.57   64.51
2    139517343969   62.44   62.44
3        -1         0.00    64.51
4        -1         0.00    64.51
5        -1         7.32    64.51
```

Comment: I see your question has 2 parts. First one is you want to compare. Please define it little more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By "compare" I mean that I need to see whether the sales for loyalty customers are greater or lesser than the sales for non-loyalty customers.

So I would need a single sum from loyalty sales and a single sum from non-loyalty sales.

Comment: Added that part. Please check and confirm if that's the expected output you are looking at.